# Inherit entities

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How to do when getting the user entity in Spring Boot, depending on the role that is the property of the user entity to get the entity that extend the user. For example, if user.role = "admin" gets an object of type Admin, which inherits User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorValue.html for that.

In example:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="ROLE", discriminatorType=STRING, length=20)
@DiscriminatorValue("user")
public class User{ ... }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("admin")
public class Admin extends User { ... }
```

If you use a EntityManager and assuming the User having the ID 1 is a admin, this might work:

```
Admin admin = (Admin) em.find(User.class, 1);
```